# XML to Dataset : How does one access a complex type within a node?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq

The XML file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ArrayOfCompany xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <Company>
        <CompanyID>Company A</CompanyID>
        <CompanyName>Company A</CompanyName>
        <CompanyRecID>1491</CompanyRecID>
        <Contacts>
            <Contact>
                <City>Birmingham</City>
                <Country>United States</Country>
                <FirstName>Steven</FirstName>
            </Contact>
            <Contact>
                <City>Birmingham</City>
                <Country>United States</Country>
                <FirstName>Natalie</FirstName>
            </Contact>
        </Contacts>
    </Company>
    <Company>
        <CompanyID>Company B</CompanyID>
        <CompanyName>Company B</CompanyName>
        <CompanyRecID>1492</CompanyRecID>
        <Contacts>
            <Contact>
                <City>Birmingham</City>
                <Country/>
                <FirstName>Greg</FirstName>
            </Contact>
            <Contact>
                <City>Birmingham</City>
                <Country/>
                <FirstName>Robert</FirstName>
            </Contact>
        </Contacts>
    </Company>
</ArrayOfCompany>
```

With two lines of code, I can take that XML file and pump it into a dataset:

```
    var dsCustomer = new System.Data.DataSet("CustomerDataSet");
    dsCustomer.ReadXml(System.IO.Path.Combine(currentAssemblyDirectoryName, "company.xml"));
```

.NET understands the schema.  This is what it looks like when I use ds.WriteXmlSchema command:
[image]

Given a company name, how can use a LINQ query to return the contacts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can parse xml with LINQ to XML:

```
var name = "Company B";
var xdoc = XDocument.Load("company.xml");
var contacts = from company in xdoc.Descendants("Company")
               where (string)company.Element("CompanyName") == name
               from contact in company.Element("Contacts").Elements()
               select new {
                   City = (string)contact.Element("City"),
                   Country = (string)contact.Element("Country"),
                   FirstName = (string)contact.Element("FirstName")
               };
```

This will return collection of anonymous objects representing contacts of selected company. Each object will have properties for city, country and first name.

Comment: @ray023 yep, LINQ is a beautiful thing :)